# bash - optional arguments in non-tail positions

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script that can take 2-4 arguments:

```
arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

`arg2` and `arg3` are mandatory and will be supplied but `arg1` and `arg4` are optional. In the three-argument case, how can I check if `arg4` was given?

If the number of arguments is four, then this is obvious; however, with exactly three arguments, I can't tell if it's `arg1` or `arg4` that isn't present, as in the following case:

```
./script arg2 arg3 arg4
```

Comment: You can't have multiple optional placement arguments like that.  Think about it.  There is no way to distinguish `arg1 arg2 arg3` from `arg2 arg3 arg4`.  You can check the number of arguments given with `$#`.

Comment: well, no way *unless* there are content restrictions -- for instance, if arg1 is always a number and arg2 can't ever be a number, then it's possible... but the OP doesn't provide enough information here to make such distinctions, and that's a needlessly fragile approach anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

As e0k comments, you need to rethink how you're passing your arguments. For optional stuff, you should use ... options. like

```
prog -a arg1 -b arg4 arg2 arg3
prog -a arg1 arg2 arg3
prog -b arg4 arg2 arg3
prog arg2 arg3
```

So

```
#!/bin/bash

arg1="default value for arg1"
arg4="default value for arg4"
while getopts a:b: opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) arg1=$OPTARG ;;
        b) arg4=$OPTARG ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
if [[ "$#" -ne 2 ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: you failed to provide 2 mandatory arguments" >&2
    exit 1
fi
arg2=$1
arg3=$2

# do stuff with "$arg1", "$arg2", "$arg3", "$arg4"
```